# fullscreen virtualbox: ubuntu version of virtualbox-ose-guest-x11 fails to install on 12.04.02

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, fullscreen

I tried to get virtualbox to run an Ubuntu 12.04.02 64-bit on fullscreen in my Windows 7 host machine, and read that I require a `virtualbox-ose-guest-x11` for it. When I try to install it on the guest Ubuntu machine, it fails with a dependencies error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution it's been to use the `Devices` menu from Virtualbox, then click in "Install guest additions..." and follow that menu.